# Save 'echo $HOME' as string R

Tags: r, bash, echo

So I'm trying to get the home directory of a remote server that I'm using in R and saving it to a variable called `local_dir`. When I try to get the directory by typing the command `local_dir<-system('echo $HOME')`, it will print the result but not actually save it to `local_dir`; instead `0` is saved. How do I actually get the name saved?

Comment: To fix it, `local_dir <- system('echo $HOME', intern = TRUE)`, though the `Sys.getenv` answer below is a better option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Sys.getenv()` function is the best way to get environment variables in R:

```
Sys.getenv("HOME")
# [1] "C:/Users/me/Documents"
```

(Ignore the coloring of `Sys`)

Comment: or `path.expand("~")`